# Object Standarization Using NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm new to NLP and to Python.
I'm trying to use object standardization to replace abbreviations with their full meaning. I found code online and altered it to test it out on a wikipedia exert. but all the code does is print out the original text. Can any one help out a newbie in need?

heres the code:

```
import nltk

lookup_dict = {'EC': 'European Commission', 'EU': 'European Union', "ECSC": "European Coal and Steel Commuinty",
               "EEC": "European Economic Community"}


def _lookup_words(input_text):
    words = input_text.split()
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in lookup_dict:
            word = lookup_dict[word.lower()]
        new_words.append(word)
        new_text = " ".join(new_words)


    print(new_text)
    return new_text


_lookup_words(
    "The High Authority was the supranational administrative executive of the new European Coal and Steel Community ECSC. It took office first on 10 August 1952 in Luxembourg. In 1958, the Treaties of Rome had established two new communities alongside the ECSC: the eec and the European Atomic Energy Community (Euratom). However their executives were called Commissions rather than High Authorities")
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any classes in NLTK for text normalizing and canonizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227527/are-there-any-classes-in-nltk-for-text-normalizing-and-canonizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the lookup dict has the abbreviations for EC and ECSC amongs the words found in your input sentence. Calling split splits the input based on whitespace. But your sentence has the words `ECSC.` and `ECSC:` ,ie these are the tokens obtained post splitting as opposed to `ECSC` thus you are not able to map the input. I would suggest to do some depunctuation and run it again.